# Angular2 get the next day

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I need to get the next day from the day clicked.
In dateClicked I have 2017-5-4.

What I have tried is as below, but I am not getting the next day

```
let dateClicked = e.date.format();
 var nextDay = new Date(dateClicked);
nextDay.setDate(dateClicked.getDate() + 1);
```

Comment: is `dateClicked` is `Date` object?

Comment: date clicked has value - 2017-05-10

Comment: check the below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding and in extension to the **@Harleen Kaur** solution

If `let dateClicked = e.date.format();` returns a date string `2017-05-10`

Then the below test code should work:

```
var dateClicked = "2017-05-10";
var nextDay = new Date(dateClicked);
nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate() + 1);
console.log(nextDay.toLocaleDateString()); //Prints "5/11/2017"
```

I replaced the `e.date.format()` with the date string and is working perfectly.

**Below is my Chrome Debugger Console screen shot:**

[image: screenshot]

**Point:** *Just copy paste the code in your chrome debugger console to see the result.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
let dateClicked = e.date.format();
var nextDay = new Date(dateClicked);
nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate() + 1);
```

Comment: This gives me the same date as dateclicked and in the format..  "Tue May 02 2017 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)" .. where as my dateClicked  is in 2017-05-02